# How to sbustract a image from another smoothly?

Tags: image, opencv

In opencv2, I have got **two binary Mat** (white is the foreground) after some process. the first Mat is a subgraph of the second one. That is to say:

```
    Mat mat_small = ....
    Mat mat_big = .....
    Mat result = someProcess(mat_small, mat_big)
```

I can do result = mat_big - mat_small.  But some contours of the mat_big remains. It looks like a long and thin shell. I want to  remove the shell.

I have tried cv::dilate and cv::erode. In most cases, it works fine, but sometimes, the long and thin shell are not removed clearly.

And , is there a way to detect things whose width is thin? If I can do that, I can also solve my problem. But I don't know how to make that.

**Update** from self-answer

From right to left, the image is Mat_big, Mat_small, Mat_minus(Mat_minus = Mat_big - Mat_small ), Mat_result:

[image]

From right to left, the image is Mat_big, Mat_small, Mat_minus(Mat_minus = Mat_big - Mat_small ), Mat_result.

In the mat_minus, I got some long and thin contours which I want to remove.

I got the result in the fourth image using  cv::erode and cv::dilate. In most cases ,it works fine, but when the long and thin contour become a little more strong, I can not remove the contour clearly.

such as this (contour become a little more strong):

[image]

the contour in the right which is long and thin is not removed after once cv::erode. of course I can do cv::erode many times to remove the long and thin contour. But that is not the reasonable method.

do you know any method to subtract one image from another smoothly?

Comment: Can you upload the images?

Comment: @Rick M.  Thanks .I've updated some images in an answer to supplement my question.

Comment: Add the details to your question instead of as an answer. Looking at the images, I would dilate the Mat_small image before subtracting to not get the "thin line" in Mat_minus. The thicker line contour tells me that you have different images so what you can do it, get the thickness and depending on that apply the erode, ie; change the kernel size depending on the depth. You can iterate row wise or get it from contour detection.